# How to generate orders of elements in $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I generate the orders of each element in $Z_2 {\times} Z_2$? I know the operation is addition mod 2. But how do I apply this operation to an element of the form $(a,b)$?

Comment: see how many times you have to add it to itself to get the identity

Comment: by the way, $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ is the [Klein Vierergruppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)

Comment: Alternatively, it’s a two-dimensional vector space over the prime field $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title from $\mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ to match the body

Comment: Given an arbitrary direct product $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n G_k$, you can prove that the order of an element $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is equal to the least common multiple of the orders of the $x_k$'s in their respective groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 $ are $(0,0), (0, 1), (1,0),$ and $(1,1).$

The order of $(0,0)$ is $1$, because $(0,0)$ is the identity element.

The order of $(0,1)$ is $2$, because $(0,1)\ne(0,0)$ but $(0,1)+(0,1)=(0,0),$ the identity element.

Can you show that the orders of $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are also $2$?